# Unable to Connect to Flask App On Docker on windows

Tags: python, docker, flask, plotly-dash, docker-network

I have a flask app (Dash plotly) and I want to run it on Docker.
I did the following things on Linux and it ran successfully:

- The code for running the flask app: `app.run_server(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')`
- expose the port in the Dockerfile: `EXPOSE 8050`
- The code for running the app inside the Dockerfile: `CMD ["python", "./app.py"]`
- From the terminal I ran: `sudo docker build -t app .`
- From the terminal I ran: `sudo docker run -p 8050:8050 --mount type=bind,source=/,target=/tmp app`

It provided me the url: 0.0.0.0.8050, and it's works fine.

However, when I downloaded Docker Toolbox on windows 10 and Did exactly the same steps it didn't launch the app on the url that was provided.

Anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: never used Docker on Windows, but maybe, you didn't accept the firewall notification and now it's blocking incoming Docker connections?

Answer (score 0):

It's because docker isn't running natively on Windows. It's running on a virtual Linux machine on Windows. So, instead of using the `0.0.0.0`, you have to check the IP of the toolbox by using:

```
docker-machine ls
```

And then replace `0.0.0.0` with the that ip

**Update:**

If you want to use the host network, you can use the host mode by `--network` host. But please note that port forward will not work.

**reference:**

https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/

Comment: Thank you it really fixed the problem!
Is there a way to keep the host without changing it by the IP of the toolbox?